# How to change my open ID to use a different google account

Tags: support, openid, login

Hello superusers,

The title says it all. I have been using email1@gmail.com to log in as lysdexic on this site and serverfault. I want to change that to email2@gmail.com, but I just can't seem to get my head around this openID setup. If I login using email2@gmail.com then it gives my some randomly generated user ID with a rep of 1. Is there a way to migrate my openID to my other email address. And it doesn't seem to let me add another open id, maybe because they are both gmail?

This is because I need to stay signed into gmail, and my google calender all day, with email2 and don't want to have to sign out everytime I want to go to serverfault.

It was just bad foresight on my part when I set up my serverfault account, I should have used email2 from the get go.

Oh and I don't really want to use google's "allow multiple accounts". I've been trying to get everything consolidated to email2.

Any ideas?

Thanks to anyone who reads and responds.

Answer (score 6):

To associate a new OpenID with your existing account:

1. Log in with your current OpenID and view [your profile page](https://superuser.com/users/51404/lysdexic).
2. Click "add openid" (if you've done this before, it will instead say "change openid").
3. Log in with your second OpenID.
4. Once you've done this, both your OpenIDs should be associated with your account. You can log in with either one and be logged into the correct account.

However, since you've already associated your new OpenID with a separate account, you'll probably need to have the duplicate account deleted.  First try the above steps, then if they don't work contact the Stack Overflow team (team@stackoverflow.com) to have them delete the duplicate account.

Comment: yes, this will work **except when you have accidentally created a duplicate account**. If you have a dupe account email us and I will merge or delete it.